# iOS Load Web Page in UIWebView from Another View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a tabbed application, with a tab that contains a UIWebView and a second tab with a Table View Controller.

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a row in the table it takes me to my other tab and loads a web page.

Here's my storyboard:
[image: My Storyboard]

This is in my implementation for the web view:

```
-(void)loadAViewer:(NSURL*)viewerURL
{
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:viewerURL];
    [sfnViewer loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

And then in the table view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get the URL from plist
    ...

    //Generate url, pass it in and switch to web view tab
    viewerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/viewer?username=%@&pw=%@&%@", web, loc, user, pass, params]];

    ViewerFirstViewController *viewerWebView = [[ViewerFirstViewController alloc] init];
    [viewerWebView loadAViewer:viewerURL];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

}
```

Currently nothing happens. I'm taken to the other tab but with a blank UIWebView - no page loads but it doesn't crash either.

//Edit - Changes made based on answer from Steve

Based on this I've added
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL viewerUrl;
in my .h file for the UIWebView tab.

I've synthesized it in the .m and added this to my viewDidLoad method.

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:viewerURL];
[sfnViewer loadRequest:requestObj];
```

In the Table View Controller I'm now doing this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get the URL from plist
    ...

    //Generate url, pass it in and switch to web view tab
    viewerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/viewer?username=%@&pw=%@&%@", web, loc, user, pass, params]];

    ViewerFirstViewController *viewerWebView = [[ViewerFirstViewController alloc] init];
    [viewerWebView setViewerUrl:viewerURL];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

}
```

Still to no avail.

Comment: What is the question here exactly? Is it not working? What error message do you get?

Comment: It doesn't load, it moves to the other tab but I'm presented with a blank view controller. Edited question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not loading because when you call `loadAViewer:` the view itself hasn't been loaded yet so the `sfnViewer` outlet won't be hooked up to the `UIWebView` in your storyboard.

You can confirm this by checking if `sfnViewer` is nil in `loadAViewer:`.

If this is the case you will have to define an `NSURL` property on the `ViewerFirstViewController` and assign to that instead of calling `loadAViewer:`. Then in the `viewWillAppear:` method you should load the URL into `sfnViewer`.

However this will result in the web view being reloaded each time the tab is accessed, you could avoid this by checking if `viewerURL` is different from the URL currently in use in the web view: `[sfnViewer.request.URL isEqual:self.viewerURL]`, if it is the same then don't create/load the request.

Comment: Edited question based on your answer to show what I just tried

Comment: P.S. sfnViewer was nil

Comment: Do you mean it's still nil in viewDidLoad?

Comment: In viewDidLoad it is not nil

Comment: I think what is happening is that viewDidLoad only gets called once - it doesn't get called when the tabs are changed

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I'd overlooked that you were using tabs. Switching it to use `viewWillAppear:` should solve your problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Somehow `[viewerWebView setViewerUrl:viewerURL];` isn't working.. It's nil by the time I do the request...

Comment: Is it because I'm doing this `ViewerFirstViewController *viewerWebView = [[ViewerFirstViewController alloc] init];` and getting a NEW view controller when there's already one there?

Comment: Yes, you will need to access it from the storyboard / directly from the tab view controller's list of controllers.

Comment: How do I go about that? I guess I can get an array from the tab bar controller but I'm not sure how to do that or how to find the right one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37745/discussion-between-steve-wilford-and-chris-byatt)

Comment: I've fixed it but now I'm having another issue. In the web view if I navigate through a link, leave the tab and come back it reloads...

Comment: I fixed this by setting a `dirty` boolean in didSelectRow